# Xpath for nth radio-button in a group

Tags: xpath, radio-button

Given that the HTML contains:

```
<div class="Animal">
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" data-bind="checked: Animal"> Cat </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" data-bind="checked: Animal"> Dog </label>
</div>
```

How do we write the following expression in XPath:

**Find the 2nd element in the `radio button` group where the `data-bind attribute` has a value of "checked: Animal"**

I've been searching for a while and I can't come up with something that works. I tried for example:

```
//input[@data-bind='checked: Animal'][2]
```

but this always selects the first option.

Answer (score 1):

```
//div[@class='radio'][2]//input[@data-bind='checked: Animal']
```

`[1], [2], [3]` work for elements that have the same parent

Comment: Since the **input** statement doesn't have a **value** attribute Happy Bird might like to get the **label** value associated with this by adding `/../text()` to the end of your xpath statement. Nice one!